# Show Newer Data first in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How would I go about displaying data from new to old? Right now it shows the oldest posts on top and each new post is placed underneath it.

```
  <?php 
   require_once('connectimage.php');

    $sql ="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo " ".$row['data']." ";
             //newest post
            //oldest post

        }
    }

    else{
        echo "fail";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);


    ?>
```

Comment: With `WHERE id=1` it kind of looks like it should only be displaying one post.

Comment: it's as simple as doing an `ORDER BY col ASC|DESC`

Comment: `$sql ="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id desc";`

Comment: Oh yeah, the title says "older data first", but the question says "from new to old". Hmm.

Comment: you should try to look for it first (i mean google it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said:- `How would I go about displaying data from new to old?`

So you need to go for `ORDER BY` clause with sort order `DESC` like below:-

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Note:-

I removed `WHERE id = 1` part because it will give you only one record not all records.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki; I've nothing to gain from this.

Read the manual on how to "order by", it's MySQL 101 stuff.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

It's all in there.

See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

Btw, community wikis have no rep gain.